# Google Sheets API with Python

Tags: python, google-api, google-sheets-api

I am attempting to connect to this Google Sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1u3Ql_Rs19PEe0mwqpsiw2wf2cUEbnSG4vZL63rh_OaE/edit?usp=sharing

Both the .json file and the .py file are saved to my desktop.

The email in the .json has been shared with the Google Sheet

I am getting a 'JSONDecodeError: Expecting value' and cannot figure out why.

I have revised the client id and key info in the .json for pirvacy as I am new to this and was not sure if sharing this was wise

Any help is greatly appreciated. thank you

python:

```
import gspread

gc = gspread.service_account(filename = 'credentials.json')

sh = gc.open('User')

worksheet=sh.sheet1

res=worksheet.get_all_records()

print(res)
```

credentials.json:

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "clear-heaven-331616",
  "private_key_id": "abcxyz",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\abcxyz=\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "my-service-account@clear-heaven.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "abcxyz",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/my-service-account%40clear-heaven-331616.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

traceback:

```
  File "C:\Users\dusti\Desktop\googlesheets.py", line 10, in <module>
    gc = gspread.service_account(filename = 'credentials.json')

  File "C:\Users\dusti\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gspread\auth.py", line 196, in service_account
    creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_service_account_file(

  File "C:\Users\dusti\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\oauth2\service_account.py", line 238, in from_service_account_file
    info, signer = _service_account_info.from_filename(

  File "C:\Users\dusti\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\auth\_service_account_info.py", line 73, in from_filename
    data = json.load(json_file)

  File "C:\Users\dusti\anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),

  File "C:\Users\dusti\anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)

  File "C:\Users\dusti\anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())

  File "C:\Users\dusti\anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value
```

Comment: what line are you getting the error on? paste in the full stacktrace. Also, have you tried using `open_by_key` instead?

Comment: I did try the open_by_key and had the same result. I have updated the post to show the traceback (I believe this is what you were after? new to this...).

Answer (score 1):

First off I would double check that you created service account credentials on google cloud console.

Then I would consider using the Google-api-Python-client library this is googles official client library.

Then you should consider using `from_json_keyfile_name`

```
"""Hello Sheets API V4."""

from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials


SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
KEY_FILE_LOCATION = '<REPLACE_WITH_JSON_FILE>'
VIEW_ID = '<REPLACE_WITH_VIEW_ID>'


def initialize_sheets():
  """Initializes an sheets API V4 service object.

  Returns:
    An authorized sheets API V4 service object.
  """
  credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
      KEY_FILE_LOCATION, SCOPES)

  # Build the service object.
  sheets = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=credentials)

  return sheets
```